# Pandas join last 2 coma separated items in cell using tldextract

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and am using the tldextract library.  I am having problems creating a new column and joining the second and third separated string.

```
#First 5 rows for testing purposes
df = pd.DataFrame(request['destinationhostname'].iloc[0:5])

    destinationhostname
0   pod51042psh.outlook.com
1   s.mrmserve.com
2   client-office365-tas.msedge.net
3   otf.msn.com
4   log.pinterest.com

#Applying tld extract on destinationhostname column
df['req'] = request.destinationhostname.apply(tldextract.extract)

    destinationhostname              req
0   pod51042psh.outlook.com         (pod51042psh, outlook, com)
1   s.mrmserve.com                  (s, mrmserve, com)
2   client-office365-tas.msedge.net (client-office365-tas, msedge, net)
3   otf.msn.com                     (otf, msn, com)
4   log.pinterest.com               (log, pinterest, com)
```

I have tried to do this next part lots of ways like the following but keep getting errors.

```
df['fld'] = df['req'].apply('.'.join[1:3])

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Or

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, ExtractResult found
```

My desired output would be:

```
    destinationhostname             req                                  fld
0   pod51042psh.outlook.com         (pod51042psh, outlook, com)          outlook.com
1   s.mrmserve.com                  (s, mrmserve, com)                   mrmserve.com
2   client-office365-tas.msedge.net (client-office365-tas, msedge, net)  msedge.net
3   otf.msn.com                     (otf, msn, com)                      msn.com
4   log.pinterest.com               (log, pinterest, com)                pinterest.com
```

Comment: I think you're looking for str.join: `df['req'].str[-2:].str.join('.')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slice the `str` object then `join`

```
df['fld'] = df.req.str[1:].str.join('.')

df

               destinationhostname                                  req            fld
0          pod51042psh.outlook.com          (pod51042psh, outlook, com)    outlook.com
1                   s.mrmserve.com                   (s, mrmserve, com)   mrmserve.com
2  client-office365-tas.msedge.net  (client-office365-tas, msedge, net)     msedge.net
3                      otf.msn.com                      (otf, msn, com)        msn.com
4                log.pinterest.com                (log, pinterest, com)  pinterest.com
```

Or as [@coldspeed has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725828/pandas-join-last-2-coma-separated-items-in-cell-using-tldextract/53725894#comment94305137_53725828), you can slice with an end of array reference.

```
df['fld'] = df.req.str[-2:].str.join('.')
```